# Left Join is sorting output data strangely

Tags: sql, vba

Can somebody please explain the reason for the phenomenon I am seeing? I am going to paste the screenshot of the code and output below to make it easy to explain my problem.

Problem: The Left Join that I am performing between two tables is sorting my output data alphabetically when I just select particular columns but not when I select all columns in my left table.

**Code 1:** This is where the sorting problem is coming:

```
SQLQuery = _
_
"SELECT TOP 10 VersionNumber, CLA_VersionNumber " & _
_
"FROM (" & _
        "[FullPolicyList$] AS FPL) " & _
        "LEFT JOIN (SELECT CLA_VersionNumber FROM [ClaimsList$]) AS CL ON CL.[CLA_VersionNumber] 
= FPL.[VersionNumber] "
```

**Output 1:**
[Open this link to see how the output looks like, the result is sorted A-Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCI7m.png)

**Code 2:**

```
 SQLQuery = _
_
  "SELECT TOP 10 * " & _
_
 "FROM (" & _
        "[FullPolicyList$] AS FPL) " & _
        "LEFT JOIN (SELECT CLA_VersionNumber FROM [ClaimsList$]) AS CL ON CL.[CLA_VersionNumber] 
= FPL.[VersionNumber] "
```

**Output 2:**
[Open this link to see how the output now looks like, the result is sorted in how it is in the left table, without alphabetically sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6NL3.png)

What do you think is causing the sorting issue when selecting particular columns instead of all columns?

Comment: You haven't provided an `ORDER BY`, so the order in which rows are returned is unpredictable, and can change between executions. The "sorting issue" is the absence of sorting.

Comment: You do not have an `order by` in either query, you therefore cannot make any assumption on the row ordering, the differences are from the internal operations carried out by the query optimizer.

Comment: If you want a predicable sorting order, add `ORDER BY` to your query.